# Is it possible to know if an input type = datetime-local is halfway filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is it possible to know if an input type = datetime-local is halfway filled? For example, if only the date or time is filled?

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control input-lg" id="dueDate" 
ng-model="jobDueDate" min="{{currentMin | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'}}" 
placeholder="Due Date" >
```

The element object value of the input tag is empty no matter if it is empty or halfway filled.

```
var valuedate = document.getElementById('dueDate');
console.log(valuedate.value());
```

Date.parse returns NaN as well for both cases. Is there a possible solution? I'm using Jquery & AngularJS if those could help. Feel free to post cleaner solutions using other input types (no extra libraries). The aim is for the user to fill both fields out.

EDIT: Field can either be left blank or fully filled. I need to know if it's half filled so I can prompt the user or calculate the required date myself.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Due Date with date and time information. I could always have two input tags but I wanted to see if I could prompt the user to finish up what he/she started or maybe I could autocomplete in the controller code.

Comment: So just check validity state. Nothing special here. You have `min` constraint just check `<ngModelController>.$error.min`.

Comment: console.log($scope.createJobForm.jobDueDate.$error) returns an empty object. createJobForm is the name of the form and jobDueDate is the name of the input tag. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've gone through all properties and methods for the input element object in jQuery as well as AngularJS for a halfway filled date and an empty one and haven't found useful differences. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You might also want to add required validation.

Comment: I don't follow. Sorry I'm quite new to AngularJS

Comment: Just add `required` attribute and check `createJobForm.jobDueDate.$error`.

Comment: Prints out 'required: true' for halfway filled and empty. Prints out empty for fully filled field.

Comment: If the field is empty of half-filled - then `required` error will be true. I guess this is what you need?

Comment: Ah sorry, I will edit the question. The field can either be left blank or fully filled. I need to know if it's half filled so I can prompt the user or calculate the required date myself.

Comment: I doubt you can check half-filled reliably. I would not try to do it. Instead propose calculated date if the field is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect half-filled field by:

```
document.querySelector('#dueDate').validity.badInput
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Besides I don't know for what you need to check if it's halfway-filled, I really doubt there's a way to do this without some hackish solution.

However, if you want to simplify the things, you could use [**`ngMessages`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) *directive* to check if it's **complete** or not.

Check this simple **demo**.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngMessages'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentMin = new Date(); // Just an example
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form role="form" name="form" novalidate>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.dueDate.$dirty && form.dueDate.$invalid }">
        <label for="dueDate">Local date time</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control input-lg" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" ng-model="jobDueDate" min="{{currentMin | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'}}" placeholder="Due Date" required>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.dueDate.$error" ng-if="form.dueDate.$dirty">
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="datetimelocal">This needs to be a valid datetime</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre ng-bind="form.dueDate | json"></pre>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd recommend you to check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages).

I hope it helps!!