# How to tell apart partially filled or invalid input of type datetime-local from the empty one?

Tags: angularjs, html, input, datetimepicker, html-input

Is there a way to know that user entered invalid date and/or time into `datetime-local` type of `<input>` as opposed to him not entering anything?

I would like to treat no input as a sign user wants to *reset/remove* datetime being edited.

I'm using `input['datetime-local']` from AngularJS – https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to know if an input type = datetime-local is halfway filled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568186/is-it-possible-to-know-if-an-input-type-datetime-local-is-halfway-filled)

Comment: The answer in that question is insufficient. 'badInput' alone doesn't give you the three states you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the state of a datetime-local like so:

```
<input id="dte" type="datetime-local">

<script>
    var myDate = document.getElementById("dte");
    myDate.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        console.log("valueMissing : " + myDate.validity.valueMissing);
        console.log("badInput : " + myDate.validity.badInput);
        console.log("valid : " + myDate.validity.valid);
        console.log("value : " + myDate.value);
    });
</script>
```

There are other values you can check, but these should fit the requirements you mention:

**Value not entered:**

`valid == false && badInput == false && valueMissing == false && value == ''`

**Value entered (but not valid):**

`valid == false && badInput == true && valueMissing == false && value == ''`

**Value entered (and valid):**

`valid = true && badInput == false && valueMissing = false && value == 'whatever date you entered'`